# d3 Axis Bug with Tiny Domain?

Tags: d3.js

I'm using **d3.js** to create a bar chart and have run into a snag with the axis functionality.  For the following code, the axis generated is showing values 0, 2, 4, 6, and 8 and repeating them.  I would expect it to only show values 0 and 2 since those are the only 2 in the domain.  [Here's the full working code in a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fr9TN/)

Here's the code that pertains to the axis only:

```
// this yScale domain is [0, 2], and the range is like [300, 3] or thereabouts
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxValue]).range([height, margin.bottom]);
// Draw a Y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('left');
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,1)")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a bug in d3.js?  Thanks for the help!

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually displaying values 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, etc. Add this to your yAxis function.

```
.tickValues([0,1,2]).tickFormat(d3.format(",.0f"))
```